# Rails 5: Interpolated Single Quote Rendered As Unicode

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby version: 2.3.1

Rails version: 5.0.5

I am using Google's dataLayer to record ecommerce events in my site. We are in the middle of an upgrade from rails 4 to 5 and I'm running into a wall with one of my rails helpers. I use a helper to generate a product_list and inject it into the view so I can send it to the dataLayer.

In rails 4 the dom reflects what I write in the helper, including the quotes I need to include for the format. In rails 5 however, the quotes are being converted to unicode and I can't figure out why or how to avoid this. This is not happening when I bind on the method in the terminal, it's only happening when it is loaded in the dom. I've tried adding sanitize(), .html_safe, converting this to a hash and converting this to JSON and nothing is working.

Right now it is working on rails 4 like this:

```
def foo     
    result += "'var1':'#{item.id}',
              'var2':'#{item.title}',
              'var3':#{item.price}},{"
    result
  end
end
```

What I get in the DOM:

```
'products': [{
  'var1':'result1',                   
  'var2':'result2',                   
  'var3': 'result3' 
}]
```

What is being returned on the DOM in rails 5:

```
'products': [{
   &#39;var1&#39;:&#39;result1&#39;,
   &#39;var2&#39;:&#39;result2&#39;,
   &#39;var3&#39;: &#39;result3&#39;
 }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you called `html_safe`, I quickly added this to a view I had in Rails 5 to attempt to replicate and here are my results:

**View Helper**

```
module HomeHelper
  def result
    "{'var1':'test'}".html_safe
  end
end
```

**View**

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
<%= result %>
```

**Generated Page**

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
{'var1':'test'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying html_safe in the helper, but putting it in the view worked instead.